# Errors on importing tensorflow on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md).

Bazel version installed : `0.4.5`
Tensorflow version installed : `1.0.0`

I get the following when I import tensorflow

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow 


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```